# Why doesn't the Library folder show up in my Users folder in OS X Mavericks

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-mavericks

I am trying to find the location of my iPhone simulator documents. But when I click on /Users/UserA I don't see Library in there. How do I turn that on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It hasn't been visible since Lion, I believe.  You can set it to *unhidden* using the `chflags` command (from Terminal.app):

```
$ chflags nohidden ~/Library
```

Answer (score 2):

In Mavericks, you can navigate to your home folder (e.g. /Users/UserA) in the Finder and choose the View > Show View Options menu item, or type <kbd>⌘J</kbd>. In the view options panel, there’s a checkbox called Show Library Folder.